# How to set Visual Studio to view VBA files as pure text?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio

I have a project which is partly written in C#/C++ and partly in Excel/VBA. I use an Excel add-in which exports all VBA code from the Excel file when I saving.

This way I can use git to store all my source code for the project in a repo.

When I open the VBA files using Team Explorer and inspect changes, all source files ending with .bas, .frm and .cls are automatically interpreted as Visual Basic .NET.

As VBA and Visual Basic are not compatible all the way, Visual Studio shows errors and suggestions for the VBA code.

How do I turn that completely off? I.e view it as pure text. Or is there any way to add VBA language editor to Visual Studio?

Comment: Rename the files with a txt extension?

Comment: @CindyMeister I hope that is a joke :)

Comment: No, I was not joking, actually. There is certainly no way to add a VBA editor to Visual Studio. You can try Tools/Options/Text Editor/Basic/VB specific to turn off error and suggestions, though.

Comment: @CindyMeister I've been trying to set it up as VB and turn it all off, but some very few suggestions still annoyingly remain.